# Array is not defined - Codewars Kata Round Robin Tournament

Tags: javascript, arrays, return

I am attempting to do this Kata - https://www.codewars.com/kata/organize-a-round-robin-tournament/train/javascript.

The task is to create a function that organizes a round robin tournament.

Example:

```
buildMatchesTable(4)
```

Should return a matrix like:

```
[
  [[1,2], [3, 4]],  // first round:  1 vs 2, 3 vs 4
  [[1,3], [2, 4]],  // second round: 1 vs 3, 2 vs 4
  [[1,4], [2, 3]]   // third round:  1 vs 4, 2 vs 3
]
```

I have created a very clunky solution that works up until the last hurdle. I am left with an array (arr6) that is an array listing all the matchups in the correct order, but as a simple array, not subarrays designating the various rounds. So I tried to create a function cut to produce an array in the correct format and it tells me arr7 is not defined.

My solution is poorly written as I am new to this, but I think the fix should be relatively simple, something to do with not returning values correctly in functions, or functions called in the wrong order. Thanks.

```js
function buildMatchesTable(numberOfTeams) {
  let n = numberOfTeams; let h = n/2; let arr = []; let arr2 = [[],[]];
  let arr3 = [...Array(n-1)].map(v => v); let arr4 = [];
//create array
for (var i = 1; i <= n; i++) {arr.push(i)} //[1, 2, 3, 4]
//split array
arr2[0] = arr.splice(0, arr.length/2);
arr2[1] = arr.splice(0, arr.length);    //[[1, 2], [3, 4]]

//create a function that produces matches in a round from array[i]
function round (arr2) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr2[0].length; i++){
      arr4.push([arr2[0][i], arr2[1][i]]);
  }
 arr2 = arr4;
 return arr2; // [[1 v 3], [2 v 4]] etc.
}
//create a function that tranforms the arr to gameweek +1 (rotate everything clockwise apart from team 1
function trans(arr2){
  //create new arr5 that is the same as arr2
  arr5 = [[],[]];
  for (var i = 0; i < arr2[0].length; i++) {
    arr5[0].push(arr2[0][i])
    arr5[1].push(arr2[1][i])
   }

   //rotate every element apart from arr2[0,0] : [[1, 3], [4, 2]]
  let h = arr2[0].length - 1;
  arr2[0][1] = arr5[1][0];
  arr2[1][h] = arr5[0][h];
  for (var i = 2; i <= h; i++){
  arr2[0][i] = arr5[0][i-1];} 
  for (var i = 0; i <= h-1; i++){
  arr2[1][i] = arr5[1][i+1];}
  return arr2;
}

function final (n, arr2, arr3){ //putting all the functions together
  for (var i = 0; i < n-1; i++){
    arr3[i] = (round(arr2));
    trans(arr2);
  }
  return arr3; // [[1, 3], [2, 4, [1, 4], [3, 2], [1, 2], [4, 3]] X 3
}

final(n, arr2, arr3)
let arr6 = arr3[0]; // arr6 = [[1, 3], [2, 4, [1, 4], [3, 2], [1, 2], [4, 3]]

function cut(arr6, n) {
  let arr7 = [];
  let index = 0;
  while (index < arr6.length) {
    arr7.push(arr6.slice(index, n/2+index));
    index += n/2;
  }
  return arr7;
}

cut(arr6, n); 

console.log(n);
console.log(arr);
console.log(arr2);
console.log(arr3[0]);
console.log(arr4);
console.log(arr6);
console.log(arr7);//not working!
//return arr7
}
buildMatchesTable(6)
```

Answer (score 1):

No wonder, you are declaring `let arr7 = [];` inside a function. Get it out of the function, on the same level as arr6, arr4, etc.

Comment: Thank you so much. I knew it would be something stupid like that. Much appreciated.